# Ajax is not connecting to the database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have made a html file file from where i want the ajax to connect to the database in background to get the value of selected city according to user pre-selected country. In brief I just need to database to load all the cities drop down menu automatically as the user selects the country in the first drop down menu?

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="GET" action="" name="form1">
Country : <select name="country" onchange="getCity('ind.php?   country='+this.value)">
 <option value="">Select Country</option>
 <option value="1">USA</option>
 <option value="2">Canada</option>
 </select>
<br />City : <div id="citydiv">
 <select name="select">
 <option>Select City</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>



<script>

function getCity(strURL)
{         
 var req = getXMLHTTP(); // fuction to get xmlhttp object
 if (req)
 {
  req.onreadystatechange = function()
 {
    if (req.readyState == 4) { //data is retrieved from server
    if (req.status == 200) { // which reprents ok status                    
    document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;
  }
 else
  { 
     alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n");
  }
  }            
  }        
 req.open("GET", strURL, true); //open url using get method
 req.send(null);
 }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

`ind.php`

```
<?php 
    $country=$_GET['country'];
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); /change the configuration if required
    if($link)
    {
       echo "connect";
    }
    if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db('country'); //change this if required
    $query="select city from city where countryid=$country";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
 ?>
    <select name="city">
    <option>Select City</option>
    <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) ?>
   <option value><?php=$row['city']?></option>

</select>
```

Comment: as far I can tell getXMLHTTP is an ajax utility.. so its never going to 'change' your url.  I think you are misunderstanding the tools you're trying to use.

Comment: @DevDonkey I have referred this link http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/change-dropdown-list-options-values-from-database-with-ajax-and-php.html

Comment: So in this manual data changed in a page element, not url.

Comment: thats an old (and horrible) tutorial.  its using the mysql driver which is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Making an AJAX request will not change your url unless you specifically change it yourself using javascript once/after/as soon as your AJAX call is made.

> To change the url with javascript you can use something like this -

```
location.replace("http://new-url");
```